# Why "ta.sqrt" is not found in version 5 in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I don't find the function ta.sqrt...
I don't understand why ?
I try with import ta but not working too

```
//@version=5
//@library=ta
indicator("Trend Extractor", overlay=false)

src=input(close, title="Source")
smooth = input.int(1, title="Smoothing", minval=1)
length = input.int(50, title="Lookback", minval=1)
offset = input.float(0.85, title= "ALMA Offset", step=0.01)
sigma = input.float(6, title= "ALMA Sigma", minval=0)
bmult = input.float(1.0, "Band Multiplier")
cblen = input.bool(false, "Custom Band Length ? (Else same as Lookback)") 
blen = input.int(20, "Custom Band Length")
highlight=input.bool(true)
fill=input.bool(true)
barcol=input.bool(false, "Bar Color")
pch = ta.change(src, smooth)/src * 100
avpch = ta.alma(pch, length, offset, sigma)
blength = cblen ? blen : length
rms = bmult*ta.sqrt(ta.sma(avpch*avpch, blength))
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 5 it’s math.sqrt

Also that’s not how you import a library, but the in built libraries like ta are already loaded